# Are there mechanical advantages and disadvantages of various front derailleur styles?

Tags: derailleur

In general there are:

- High clamp
- Low clamp
- Braze on
- Top pull
- Bottom pull

And in particular, is any of those better choice regarding reliability and durability for touring bicycle.

Comment: I don't have a proper answer, but I have been a kind of Bike Dr Frankenstein, and have assembled numerous front derailleurs to bikes they shouldn't fit, even converted or adapted bottom pull to top pull and vice versa. And as a conclusion, Once fully adjusted, they work just as fine. Is it worth the hassle and the time? Depends on your objectives, but mostly not. If it is a straight fit to your bike, it should work, provided that it is designed for the number and size of chainrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touring → fenders. So, you need enough space for the rear fender. That's why a bottom-pull design is preferred.
Most of the touring bikes designed to use this type of derailleurs.
About high clamp/low clamp/braze on — this is frame-specific.